# Is there a way to set the default sort order in Nagios' status.cgi?

Tags: nagios

I'm hoping there's a way in a config file or something that will allow me to set the default sorting order of the status.cgi output. By default it sorts by the "host" column, ascending. I'd like to change the default to "host", but descending. (Or, if I could force hosts to appear in a specific order by default, that's acceptable too.)

I changed the index.php to set the "main" window as "status.cgi?host=all&sorttype=2&sortoption=1", which does what I want, but only when the frame is created, obviously. Clicking the "View status detail for all hosts" on one of the subpages will put it back to "host" ascending.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for the stock CGI frontend to do this, that I'm aware of. You are, of course, free to add that functionality; it's just compiled C code, nothing fancy about it.

You *might* find this functionality in one of the alternate frontends, though (like [Thruk](http://www.thruk.org)). There is an entire category of web frontends on [Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org)